# What are the rules to determine if a set is a basis for V?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

So I have here an example, we let $S = \{t^2 + 1, t - 1, 2t + 2\}$

How can I determine if $S$ is a basis for $V = P_2$?

Also, do I need to prove that $S$ is linearly independent? I'm almost there, just need someone to actually point me in the right direction. Please help.

Comment: Yes, just to show $S$ is linearly independent is ok.

Comment: Thank for the edit @Casteels. Thank you, but is that enough?

Comment: @user66240 Do you already know any basis of $P_2$? What about the dimension of $P_2$? These are useful facts on which answers might depend on.

Comment: Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb F$ with dimension $n$. If you have an $n$ linearly independent vectors then they must be a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, we need to prove two statements:

1. $S=\{s_1,s_2,s_3\}$ is linearly independent, so any element in $S$ is not a linear combination of anothers, i.e.,
   $$as_1+bs_2+cs_3=0$$
   for scalars $a,b,c$ not all zero; and
2. $V$ es generated by $S$ (or $S$ spans $V$); briefly $V=\text{span}(S)$. To do that, we pick an arbitrary element $v$ in $V$, and show that 
   $$as_1+bs_2+cs_3=v$$
   for scalars $a,b,c$ (possibly all zero).

In your case

1. In order to prove that $S = \{t^2+1,t-1,2t+2\}$ is linearly independent, we need to show that the only solution for
   $$a(t^2+1)+b(t-1)+c(2t+2)=0$$
   is the trivial solution (i.e., $a=b=c=0$).
   You can "translate" to linear system equations. Note that
   $$xt^2+yt+z\sim(x,y,z)$$ and so
   $$\begin{matrix}t^2&&+1&\sim&(1, \ \ \ 0,\ \ \ 1)\\ &t&-1&\sim&(0, \ \ \ 1,-1)\\ &2t&+2&\sim&(0, \ \ \ 2, \ \ \ 2)\end{matrix}$$
   Thus, we need to solve
   $$a(1,0,1)+b(0,1,-1)+c(0,2,2)=0$$
   i.e.,
   $$\begin{matrix}a&\cdot&\color{red}{1}&+&b&\cdot&\color{blue}{\ \ \ 0}&+&c&\cdot&\color{green}{0}&=&0\\ a&\cdot&\color{red}{0}&+&b&\cdot&\color{blue}{\ \ \ 1}&+&c&\cdot&\color{green}{2}&=&0\\ a&\cdot&\color{red}{1}&+&b&\cdot&\color{blue}{-1}&+&c&\cdot&\color{green}{2}&=&0\end{matrix}$$
2. In the same fashion, we need to solve
   $$a(1,0,1)+b(0,1,-1)+c(0,2,2)=(x,y,z)$$ for arbitrary $xt^2+yt+z$ in $P_2$, 
   i.e.,
   $$\begin{matrix}a&\cdot&\color{red}{1}&+&b&\cdot&\color{blue}{\ \ \ 0}&+&c&\cdot&\color{green}{0}&=&x\\ a&\cdot&\color{red}{0}&+&b&\cdot&\color{blue}{\ \ \ 1}&+&c&\cdot&\color{green}{2}&=&y\\ a&\cdot&\color{red}{1}&+&b&\cdot&\color{blue}{-1}&+&c&\cdot&\color{green}{2}&=&z\end{matrix}$$
   If we can solve $a,b,c$ regard to $x,y,z$, then we are done. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you for explaining it beatifuly. i found out that S is not a basis of V. As i've solved the equation, S is linearly dependent and does not span to S. :)

Comment: 1. a = 0; b = -2c; -> which is linearly dependent. 
2. a = x; b + 2c = z; -> S does not span for V.

Comment: I haven't solved. But I think $S$ is L.I.: one has a first component to $1$, the remains, to $0$; and the others have diferent sign. By other hand, also I think $S$ spans; computed this $A = s_3 + (-2)s_1$, $B = s_2 + s_1$, and $(A + 2B)/4$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the answer. Correct me if I am wrong:

A set of vector S in a vector space V is called a basis of V if S spans V and S is linearly independent.

We just need to answer the question: Does S spans V? and Is S Linearly Independent?

Comment: Yes indeed, that is how the definition of a basis reads. Did they teach you about bases without giving a definition?

Comment: You are correct that this answers the question in the title, but not the question in the question's body. Perhaps you should clarify the question. And maybe add the tag (definition) because it seems you're after the definition of basis.

Comment: I know how to check independence. How do i check spanning?

Comment: @GitGud, sir because I said that was just an example. I thought I was making myself clear but turns out misleading. Sorry for that.

Comment: The basic method to check spanning is that you can write any vector in the space as linear combination of the given set of vectors (treat the coefficients as unknowns; show that the linear system so obtained always has at least one solution). If you know things about dimension, there is a shortcut here: $n$ linearly independent vectors in a space of dimension $n$ are always a spanning set for the space. This applies in the example fore $n=3$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, what i did was equate a(t^2)+bt+c = c_1(t^2 + 1) + c_2(t - 1) + c_3(2t + 2).

Comment: Yes. If you can solve $c_1,c_2,c_3$ for every triple $a,b,c$ (as indeed you can) then you will have have shown that $t^2+1$, $t-1$ and $2t+2$ form a spanning set of $P_2$.

Comment: Great! thank you very much! +1 for you

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, after solving i found out that S is linearly dependent. Does that mean S is not a basis?

Comment: @user66240: That is curious, since they look linearly independent to me. Can you say which non-trivial relation you found than makes them linearly dependent?

Comment: i got  
1. a = 0; b = -2c; -> which is linearly dependent. 2. a = x; b + 2c = z; -> S does not span for V.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  The determinat of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}  1&0&1 \\ -1 &1&0\\2&2&0 \end{pmatrix}$ is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To prove linear independence you can use the [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Definition).